# Всем привет. Запарсил сайт, но что то не так. Вместо вывода опр.текста выходят пустые скобки []

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.forbes.ru/')
response = response.content
html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
res = html.find_all(class_='_3g9mx_3B1eS')
res2 = [c.text for c in res ]
print(res2)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу вывести информацию в виде текста (во вкладке 'новости' на сайте) но при запуске выводится только это: []

Comment: Вы, для начала, сделайте дебаг вашего кода и посмотрите содержимое переменной `res`.

Comment: Значит тегов с указанным классом в html нет.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это **вообще** не так делается‥ Попробую разжевать.

### Где брать данные?

Давай, для начала, откроем страницу [forbes.ru](https://www.forbes.ru/) и посмотрим что там происходит. По комментариям вижу, что есть желание получить *новости* из *вкладки*, какой вкладки? На сайте есть колонка с новостями слева. Про неё речь?

Допустим про неё, поехали. Крутим эту колонку, видим scroll, видим, что в конце появляется кружок загрузки и‥ подгружаются новые новости. Так вот, пишем себе в заметки, [beautiful-soup](/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) — это парсер. Парсер для статичных страниц либо же для того, что мы получаем через `requests` или более окольными путями.

Для понимания, идём в **developer tools** в любом браузере, например в **Chrome** жмём <kbd>F12</kbd> и идём в вкладку **Network**, смотрим самую первую запись при фильтре **All**, а именно *[www.forbes.ru](http://www.forbes.ru)*, правее выбираем вкладку *Preview*.

[image: Как новости видит BeautifulSoap]

Вот таким вот образом [beautiful-soup](/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) увидит страницу с обычным `GET` **request** как в вопросе, обращающимся по [адресу](https://www.forbes.ru/).
Да, там есть новости, заголовок даже распарсить можно:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
response = requests.get('https://www.forbes.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all("p", string=re.compile(r"Новости"))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
[<p class="_1YaJk">
       Новости
     </p>]
```

Толку только от этого мало будет. Да, можем пойти в `parent`, искать сиблинги, выйти в итоге на `div`, `ul` и `li`, но они будут пустыми, потому что страница грузится динамически и то что [beautiful-soup](/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) получает на покушать с обычного request наглядно показано выше на скрине.

Пытливый ум начнёт разбираться, а где же происходит динамическая прогрузка и как нам её выцепить. Можно, конечно, воспользоваться **Selenium** или **Scrapy**, но это неинтересно и это не путь война.
Можно попробовать заблокировать *cdn.forbes.ru* и увидеть, что новости больше не грузятся, это потому что с этого адреса прилетают `JS` скрипты, которые расфасовывают информацию по `DOM`.
А берут они информацию из *waterfall.forbes.ru*, который тоже для наглядности можно попробовать заблокировать и убедиться, что новости будут пустыми, при этом весь остальной сайт останется рабочим. В общем, источник нашли.

### Websocket

Что это за **request**? `101`, о божечки, да это же [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket)! 
Все любят веб сокеты, а если вы их ещё не любите, то самое время полюбить.
На самом деле весь путь описанный выше проходить необязательно, это лишь для наглядности и в целях обучения. В вкладке **Network** есть фильтр **WS**, можно заглянуть туда сразу и посмотреть, использует ли сайт сокеты.

Итак, убедились, что использует. Выбираем его и смотрим вкладку **Messages** в Chrome или **Response** в лисичке. Смотрим для того, чтобы научиться с этим сокетом общаться. Браузер отправляет `basic`, получает словарь с массивом внутри.
Прокручиваем новости вниз до кружка загрузки, видим, что теперь отправляется `more`. Всё это можно потыркать:

[image: Как смотреть сообщения сокетов]

Поздравляю, мы научились общаться с сокетом, осталось только переложить всё это дело на код:

```python
from websocket import create_connection
from datetime import datetime
import json

def get_news_from_socket(request, socket):
    socket.send(request)
    response = socket.recv()
    out = json.loads(response)
    return out['data']['base'] if request == 'basic' else out['data']

ws = create_connection('wss://waterfall.forbes.ru/ws')

data = []
data += get_news_from_socket('basic', ws)
data += get_news_from_socket('more', ws)

ws.close()

for d in data:
    print('{}\r\n{}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d['time']))
                                      , d['title']
                                      , 'https://forbes.ru/'+d['url']))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
2022-12-04 17:17:35
ОПЕК+ сохранила план ограничения добычи нефти на фоне введения потолка цен 
https://forbes.ru/biznes/482023-opek-sohranila-plan-ogranicenia-dobyci-nefti-na-fone-vvedenia-potolka-cen

2022-12-04 16:02:13
Власти рекомендовали госкомпаниям проявить «сдержанность» в тратах на Новый год
https://forbes.ru/society/482022-vlasti-rekomendovali-goskompaniam-proavit-sderzannost-v-tratah-na-novyj-god

...

2022-12-01 11:00:00
Устройство с умом: как технологии помогают развивать инклюзивность в образовании
https://forbes.ru/forbeslife/481747-ustrojstvo-s-umom-kak-tehnologii-pomogaut-razvivat-inkluzivnost-v-obrazovanii

2022-12-01 10:15:03
Театральные премьеры и книжная ярмарка: афиша с 1 по 7 декабря
https://forbes.ru/forbeslife/481824-teatral-nye-prem-ery-i-kniznaa-armarka-afisa-s-1-po-7-dekabra
```

По хорошему тут всё надо оборачивать в `async` и т.д., но для простоты понимания данного решения оставляю всё максимально просто.

1. `create_connection('wss://waterfall.forbes.ru/ws')` — создаём подключение к сокету.
   Адрес берём из вкладки **Headers**.
2. `ws.send()` — отправка сообщения сокету. Первый раз `'basic'`, все последущие разы `'more'`.
3. `ws.recv()` — принимаем ответное сообщение от сокета. Вот тут асинхронность не помешала бы, но пусть так будет.
4. Далее парсим всё это дело через `json.loads()`, потому что это **json**, ключи опять же смотрим в браузере, на этапе когда тыркали сокет.
5. `ws.close()` — не забываем закрыть сокет.
   Он, в общем то, закроется сам по timeout, но так как мы вежливые люди, закроем его принудительно.

#### Послесловие

В зависимости от того, сколько ты новостей хочешь получить, можешь отправлять `'more'` несколько раз и получать новый массив с более давними новостями, но сильно не увлекайся, а то форбс даст по рогам