# Парсинг плэйлистов vk

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте, beautiful-soup

Вопрос следующий, мне нужно спарсить данные по ссылке: https://vk.com/music/playlist/304750709_375

А именно данные из класса audioPlaylist__genres

Если перейти не авторизованным на сайт, то можно увидеть что класс содержит следующие данные:
“5M прослушиваний · обновлён сегодня в 13:43”

Если начать парсить через BeautifulSoup

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
URL = 'https://vk.com/music/playlist/304750709_375'
req = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
listen = soup.find("div", class_="audioPlaylist__genres")
print(listen)
```

То результат будет следующим:

```html
<div class="audioPlaylist__genres">4.9M прослушиваний · обновлён сегодня в 13:43</div>
```

Без парсинга результат **5М**, а после парсинга **4.9М**. Такая ситуация случается, как я понял, из за того что в первом случае число округляется.

Если авторизоваться в VK и посмотреть ту же страницу, то можно увидеть следующий результат (https://vk.com/audios26845044?block=my_playlists&section=all&z=audio_playlist304750709_375):
“**4 954 179** прослушиваний обновлён сегодня в 15:43”

Отсюда следующие вопросы: Получается, что на страницу передается полное число (4 954 179) но уже на ней преобразуется в вид 4.9М? Если, все так, то как я могу спарсить именно полное число (4 954 179), будучи не авторизованным на сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Без парсинга результат 5М, а после парсинга 4.9М. Такая ситуация случается, как я понял, из за того что в первом случае число округляется.

Нет, такая ситуация получается, потому что BS видит мобильную версию сайта. В мобильной версии сайта **4.9М**, в десктопной **5М**.

Чтобы таких казусов больше не случалось, передавай правильный User-Agent в `headers`:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
URL = 'https://vk.com/music/playlist/304750709_375'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'}
req = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')
listen = soup.find_all("div", class_="AudioPlaylistSnippet__info")
print(listen)
```

###### Вывод:

```console
[<div class="AudioPlaylistSnippet__info">
      970 аудиозаписей
  </div>, <div class="AudioPlaylistSnippet__info">
    5M прослушиваний · обновлён вчера в 13:43
  </div>]
```

---

> Получается, что на страницу передается полное число (4 954 179) но уже на ней преобразуется в вид 4.9М?

Нет, получается, что без авторизации с страницы https://vk.com/audios26845044?block=my_playlists&section=all&z=audio_playlist304750709_375 перенаправляет на https://vk.com/music/playlist/304750709_375

На результирующей странице, после редиректа, полное число не передаётся, php возвращает именно **5M**, округление идёт на стороне backend, которое ты никак не увидишь.

Полное же число можно найти в POST запросе, который делается для формирования всплывающего окна.

---

> как я могу спарсить именно полное число (4 954 179), будучи не авторизованным на сайте

К счастью, POST запрос из первой ссылки прекрасно работает без авторизации:

```python
import requests
import re

url = r'https://vk.com/al_audio.php'
params = {'act': 'load_section'}
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
data = {
    'al': 1,
    'owner_id': 304750709,
    'playlist_id': 375,
    'type': 'playlist'
}
r = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, params=params)
print(int(re.search(r'(?<="listens":")\d+', r.text).group(0)))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
4958352
```

Тут `r` (response) можно парсить через BeautifulSoup, можно преобразить через `json.loads`, но если кроме числа прослушиваний ничего не надо, то достаточно и [регулярные-выражения](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), они отрабатывают на 5% быстрее на единичном запросе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Денис [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: А можете сказать откуда вы взяли:

data = {
    'al': 1,
    'owner_id': 304750709,
    'playlist_id': 375,
    'type': 'playlist'
}

Comment: @Денис Ха, сейчас сложно уже сказать  Но, вообще, смотрите что в браузере по запросам выдаёт, как это делать можно почитать [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472710/Всем-привет-Запарсил-сайт-но-что-то-не-так-Вместо-вывода-опр-текста-выходят-п/1473982#1473982)