# Как правильно выбирать значения для парсинга на Wildberries?

Tags: python, парсер

Совсем не понимаю, как мне выбирать значения для парсера, в следствии дальше чем сейчас продвинуться сложно.

У меня есть страница сайта например: https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/aksessuary/golovnye-ubory?sort=popular&page=1&xsubject=79&fkind=3&bid=61d74198-f541-45e3-9ac1-917a8f3bd2eb

на этом сайте, предположим я хочу спарсить абсолютно все товары с первой страницы, у меня есть строчка: `items = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "product-card__main j-card-link"})` ,
когда я пытаюсь вывести значения, они не выводятся и программа не выдаёт ошибки.

Вот код:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

BASE_URL = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/aksessuary/golovnye-ubory?sort=popular&page=1&xsubject=79&fkind=3&bid=61d74198-f541-45e3-9ac1-917a8f3bd2eb"
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": UserAgent().random}

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(BASE_URL, headers=HEADERS) as response:
            r = await aiohttp.StreamReader.read(response.content)
            soup = BS(r, "html.parser")
            items = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product-card__main j-card-link"})
            
            for item in items:
                print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Учитесь анализировать сайты, ведь это не просто HTML, а зачастую целая цепочка различных вызовов, где данные получаются при помощи отправки запроса на API сервера, а он в ответ дает JSON со всем нужным. Указанный вами сайт [не исключение](https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/head_accessories2/catalog?appType=1&cat=9967&curr=rub&dest=-1257786&emp=0&fkind=3&lang=ru&locale=ru&page=1&reg=0&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,1,48,22,66,31,40,71&sort=popular&spp=0&xsubject=79). Писал однажды [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) про то, как получить запрос, и как убрать лишнее.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wildberries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как понять что парсить и как пользоваться **developer console** довольно полно расписал [в данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1473982/531666). Повторяться не буду, шаги примерно те же, только тут без сокетов.

Что имеем здесь?
Здесь каталог можно удобно получить в [json](/questions/tagged/json) по адресу catalog.wb.ru, а конкретно по этому адресу:

```console
https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/head_accessories2/catalog?cat=9967&curr=rub&dest=-1257786&fkind=3&page=1&regions=80,64,38,4,115,83,33,68,70,69,30,86,75,40,1,66,48,110,31,22,71,114,111&sort=popular&spp=0&xsubject=79
```

Копируем в [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), никакие авторизации не нужны, api открытый. Запрос работает и выдаёт товары, всё, задача решена.

## Параметры

Но просто копировать вставлять запрос из браузера дико не интересно, правда же?
Предлагаю разобраться в составляющих запроса.

Какие тут есть параметры?

- **cat** — 9967
  Циферки. Берутся они [отсюда](https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol0/data/main-menu-ru-ru-v2.json), соответственно можно искать по названию категории и потом использовать в запросе.
- **curr** — rub
  Тут, думаю, объяснять не надо. Ну а существующие на сайте курсы можно взять [отсюда](https://static-basket-01.wb.ru/vol0/data/settings-front-ru.json).
- **dest** — -1257786
  Берётся [отсюда](https://user-geo-data.wildberries.ru/get-geo-info?latitude=60.753737&longitude=37.6201&address=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD), в качестве параметров GPS координаты, адрес можно указать любой он на результат не влияет, но если его не указать, то координаты не сработают и выдаст стандартные. Забираем всё с **xinfo**
- **fkind** — 3
  Если данный параметр не указывать, результат на первый взгляд не поменялся, можно глубоко не изучать.
- **page** — 1
  Очевидно номер страницы
- **regions** — 80,64,38,4,115,83,33,68,70,69,30,86,75,40,1,66,48,110,31,22,71,114,111
  Опять циферки, много циферок!
- **sort** — popular
  Опять же, совершенно необязательный параметр, сортировка по дефолту идёт по популярным. Чтобы понять какие есть вариант, надо потыкать сайт и смотреть запросы. Возможно они где-то даже указаны, искать сейчас не будем, оставим вам на домашнее задание.
- **spp** — 0
  Очередной параметр который в моём случае не меняет ничего.
- **xsubject** — 79
  Наконец-то что-то интересное. Это подкатегории товаров, которые можно получить в [фильтрах по категории](https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/head_accessories2/v4/filters?cat=9967&dest=-1257786).

### Код

Отлично, с параметрами разобрались, теперь у нас есть всё, чтобы забрать данные по нескольким категориям, по нескольким городам для сравнения цен и т.д. Делать мы это, конечно же, не будем, но следующий код можно будет адаптировать под цели:

```python
import urllib.parse
import requests
import pprint

# Сюда будем собирать параметры
catalog_params = {}

# Тут ищем id категории. Можно вместо поиска парсить все категории,
# можно прикрутить near match для названия категорий, смысл думаю понятен
for cat in categories:
    if cat['name'] == 'Аксессуары':
        for child in cat['childs']:
            if child['name'] == 'Головные уборы':
                catalog_params['cat'] = child['id']

# Получаем координаты любого адреса, пусть будет доставка в Областную Думу в Магадане
address = 'улица Горького, 8А, Магадан'
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'
coords = requests.get(url).json()

params = {
    'latitude': coords[0]["lat"],
    'longitude': coords[0]["lon"],
    'address': 'Город чудес и вкусных морепродуктов'
}
r = requests.get('https://user-geo-data.wildberries.ru/get-geo-info', params = params).json()
# Парсим строку с полученными данными и добавляем к параметрам
catalog_params.update({p.split('=')[0]:p.split('=')[1] for p in r['xinfo'].split('&')})

# xsubject забирается также как и основная категория
# Не буду повторяться, просто пропишем
catalog_params['xsubject'] = 79

# Ну и в конце-концов
r = requests.get('https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/head_accessories2/catalog', params = catalog_params).json()

pprint.pprint(r['data']['products'][0:2], depth=2)
```

###### Вывод:

```
[{'__sort': 61167,
  'brand': 'lafreice',
  'brandId': 121717,
  'colors': [...],
  'diffPrice': False,
  'dist': 10003,
  'feedbacks': 199,
  'id': 40036810,
  'kindId': 2,
  'ksort': 54000,
  'logisticsCost': 35500,
  'name': 'Меховые наушники',
  'panelPromoId': 158688,
  'pics': 16,
  'priceU': 74100,
  'promoTextCat': 'КОСМИЧЕСКИЕ СКИДКИ',
  'rating': 5,
  'root': 30057509,
  'sale': 0,
  'saleConditions': 0,
  'salePriceU': 100500,
  'siteBrandId': 131717,
  'sizes': [...],
  'subjectId': 79,
  'subjectParentId': 6,
  'supplierId': 68077,
  'time1': 17,
  'time2': 257,
  'volume': 60},
 {'__sort': 58003,
  'brand': 'lafreice',
  'brandId': 121717,
  'colors': [...],
  'diffPrice': False,
  'dist': 10003,
  'feedbacks': 363,
  'id': 39884574,
  'kindId': 5,
  'ksort': 51786,
  'logisticsCost': 26600,
  'name': 'Меховые наушники кошка',
  'pics': 6,
  'priceU': 46200,
  'rating': 5,
  'root': 29487176,
  'sale': 0,
  'saleConditions': 0,
  'salePriceU': 70700,
  'siteBrandId': 131717,
  'sizes': [...],
  'subjectId': 79,
  'subjectParentId': 6,
  'supplierId': 68077,
  'time1': 17,
  'time2': 257,
  'volume': 45}]
```