# Парсинг количества товара на Wildberries

Tags: python, парсер

Есть задача спарсить остатки товара с помощью только requests. Selenium, bs4 и пр. библиотеки использовать нельзя.
В ручном режиме остатки можно увидеть на странице корзины, если добавлять туда товар. То есть, добавляем товар в корзину, идём в неё и там играемся с количеством.
Начинаю с самого первого пункта плана. Добавление товара в корзину - это post вот на такой url (в декодированном виде):

> https://a.wb.ru/e/ec?t=iPhone 14 Pro Max 1TB (США) Apple 139760729 купить за 153 992 ₽ в интернет-магазине Wildberries&u=https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/139760729/detail.aspx&cid=4&s=800x980x24&w=400x490&user_id=6292790831681475795&vbn=324&r=https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/139760729/detail.aspx

Часть параметров из карточки товара, s, w - это размеры экрана устройства, насколько мне удалось разобраться. Что есть vbn и откуда брать user_id? Последний сохраняется в куках, но достать его с помощью стандартного подхода не получается - куки сессии в итоге пустые:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get("https://www.wildberries.ru/",
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': '*/*'
    },    
)
print(s.cookies)
```

Как получить куки? Или может сам подход неправильный? Занимаюсь этим впервые.

Comment: А вопросы-ответы тут поиском по слову "wildberries" уже изучили, там нет нужных ответов? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wildberries

Comment: Нет, не нашлось. Гугление тоже не привело ни к чему толковому. В основном все получают карточку товара и работают дальше уже с ней, но количества остатков там нет. Видно, без post не обойтись, вопрос - как это сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А ведь интересная задачка 
В том смысле, что проверять количество товаров в наличии через насилие корзины — довольно остроумно. Не знаю зачем это вам, но поехали.

## Получаем cookies

Тут вы, в общем то, делаете всё правильно, создаёте сессию, в сессии они будут храниться. В большинстве случаев cookies появятся там сами после первого GET запроса, но… тут у нас немного посложнее будет.

Печенюх у нас не так много, можно посмотреть в браузере, какие есть.
А это:

- ___wbs
- ___wbu
- __wba_s
- _wbauid
- BasketUID

### Как их получать?

Если cookies не подтягиваются автоматически, первое что стоит попробовать, это поискать содержание запросов на предмет `set-cookie`, т.к. именно там в headers они могут быть присвоены. Поищем.

Для этого идём в developer console, вкладка Network, с которой вы уже знакомы, и ищем где ставятся cookies.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую браузер Firefox, но в Chrome всё выглядит примерно так же. Стоит также отметить, что поиск надо вести во вкладке **Search**, а не filter URLs, это два разных поиска. В Chrome-based браузерах для этого необходимо нажать на лупу, она находится сверху-слева в панели инструментов.

Чтож, супер, нашли!
**BasketUID** можно уже забирать.

```python
import requests

s = requests.Session()
headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
s.post('https://www.wildberries.ru/webapi/basket/info', headers=headers)

print(s.cookies)
```

###### Вывод:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie BasketUID=d874176e-4c6d-4b29-b582-5f14a07f6506 for .wildberries.ru/>]>
```

Sanitize делать не буду, с каждой новой сессией UID будет новый, так что не страшно его здесь показать.

Чудно, также видим **__wbs** и **__wbu**, которые можно получить, но… Смотрим запрос, в request headers уже указаны **__wba_s**, **_wbauid** и **BasketUID**. Копируем в [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), или же используем **Edit and Resend** в Firefox, пробуем убрать cookies в request и смотрим дадут ли их нам в response. Хмм, забавно, выдают.

По итогу можем получить всё кроме **_wbauid**, который нам нужен, а его нет. Какой вывод можно сделать? Он берётся откуда-то из [js](/questions/tagged/js) скриптов, придётся помучаться.

### Забираем cookie из javascript

⚠ Должен отметить, что я не гуру JS, поэтому, возможно, есть более простые и эффективные подходы.

Итак, метод дедукции приводит нас к тому, что **_wbauid** получается откуда то из [js](/questions/tagged/js). Проверяем теорию, [запрещаем скрипты](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/954712) в dev console и стираем cookies в браузере.

Методом тыка (а есть более простой метод?) запрещаем все скрипты и по одному разрешаем. Оказывается, что **_wbauid** присваивается в `/sdk/sdk.js`.

Придётся заглянуть в js код. В ряде случаев, кода очень много. Учитывая, что искомый id мы не нашли в запросах, он может как-то банально рассчитываться, либо же на основе нескольких нетривиальных запросов. Anyway, смотрим код. Используем pretty print, иначе минифицированное полотно смотреть невозможно. Пробуем банальный поиск по **_wbauid**.

Опа, а вот и код где он создаётся:

```js
o.prototype.genNewUserID = function() {
    var t = Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1e3)
      , e = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 30)).toString() + t.toString()
      , n = new Date;
    return n.setTime(n.getTime() + 31536e6),
    document.cookie = "_wbauid=" + e + "; expires=" + n.toUTCString() + "; path=/; domain=" + this._cookieDomain,
    e
}
```

Можно поставить breakpoint и посмотреть значения в момент создания, чтобы убедиться, что всё правильно нашли. Да-да, это тот самый ID!

Как видно, это довольно простые расчёты без запросов.
Осталось повторить этот код на [python](/questions/tagged/python) и получить долгожданный [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie).

1. Получаем `t`:
   Аналогом [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) является [`.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).
   Интересно, что JS выдаёт целочисленное число из 13 цифр, Python выдаёт 16 цифр, но 6 из них в дроби. Соответственно `/ 1e3` нам не нужно, достаточно написать `int()` и будет округление до целочисленного числа аналогичное `Math.floor()`. Кода получается даже меньше, результат тот же, целочисленное число из 10 цифр.
2. Получаем `e`:

   - аналогом [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) будет [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random).
     В качестве разницы, возможно они выдают разное максимальное количество после запятой, но учитывая дальнейшее округление это не так важно.
   - аналогом `Math.pow(2, 30)` будет `pow(2,30)`.
     Но, не совсем понятно зачем это делать, результат будет всегда одним и тем же, так что можно просто взять результат — 1073741824.
   - Результат округляется вниз, уже знаем, что для этого есть `int()`
   - Ну и вместо `toString()` будет `str()`.
3. получаем `n`:
   Так, а что здесь происходит? Если переводить на Python, то получим:
   `n = datetime.now()`
   `n = datetime.fromtimestamp((int(n.timestamp()*1000) + 31536e6) / 1000)`
   Помним ведь про разницу в 13 и 16 цифр после запятой? Поэтому получается так страшно, но по сути нам надо просто добавить год и отнять один день, поэтому код будет выглядеть гораздо проще.
4. Добавляем cookie.
   Как это правильно сделать?
   Вариантов разобраться с этим много. Можно подсмотреть [готовый ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904567/8489602), но лично меня всегда распирает от любопытства, откуда например взялась опция 1?
   В целом, создавать свои cookies, конечно, не рекомендуется, но в нашем случае необходимо. Смотрим тип через `type(s.cookies)`. Вторую опцию можно подсмотреть в документации [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html) и [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html), первую же через `dir(s.cookies)` и `s.cookies.set.__code__.co_varnames`.

#### В итоге

```python
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import random

s = requests.Session()
n = datetime.now()
t = int(n.timestamp())
e = str(int(random.random() * pow(2,30))) + str(int(t))
n = n + relativedelta(years=1) - relativedelta(days=1)
s.cookies.set('_wbauid', e, domain='.wildberries.ru', expires=int(n.timestamp()))
```

---

## Получаем количество доступного товара

> Есть задача спарсить **остатки товара** с помощью **только requests**.

> <s>Как получить куки?</s> Или может сам подход неправильный? Занимаюсь этим впервые.

C [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie) разобрались. Но, они нам не пригодятся. Зачем я про них расписывал? Если, вдруг, будет необходимо автоматизировать заказ товаров, то, конечно же, для корзины они пригодятся.

Но наша задача довольно тривиальна.

> Добавление товара в корзину - это post вот на такой url (в декодированном виде):

Даже если занимаетесь "*впервые*" ход мыслей правильный. 
Но есть нюанс.
Попробуйте заблокировать `https://a.wb.ru/e/ec` (block URL) и посмотреть что будет. Корзина продолжает работать! Как же так? Не берусь судить, что делает указанный вами url, возможно статистику отправляет, возможно на стороне backend в корзину добавляет, но если его повторить "Edit and Resend" в корзине ничего не меняется.
Так, а что ещё происходит после нажатия кнопки? Если заблокировать **basketAdderHelper.min.js** и / или **basketAdderAdapter.min.js** тогда корзина не сработает. Но они на сервер ничего не отправляют.
Также если заблокировать GET запрос `card.wb.ru/cards/detail` то… Сайт напишет, что товара нет в наличии.

Стоп, что?
Именно это мы и ищем, наличие. Как это работает, JS подготавливает данный GET запрос и‥ пишет в local storage. Так что, если кому-то придёт в голову автоматизировать покупку товаров в корзине знаете куда смотреть и где она формируется. Локально.

Нам же достаточно посмотреть в GET запрос, как раз таки там и содержится информация которую ищем, корзину для этого насиловать не надо.

```python
import requests
import urllib.parse

s = requests.Session()

address = 'Ивановская площадь, Москва'
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'
coords = requests.get(url).json()

params = {
    'latitude': coords[0]["lat"],
    'longitude': coords[0]["lon"],
    'address': 'Город чудес'
}
r = s.get('https://user-geo-data.wildberries.ru/get-geo-info', params = params).json()
params = {p.split('=')[0]:p.split('=')[1] for p in r['xinfo'].split('&')}

search_params = {
    'query': 'iPhone',
    'resultset': 'catalog',
    'page': 1
}
search_params.update(params)

url = 'https://search.wb.ru/exactmatch/ru/common/v4/search'
r = s.get(url, params=search_params).json()

card_params = params
url = 'https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail'

for ix, product in enumerate(r['data']['products'][:10]):
    card_params['nm'] = product['id']
    r = s.get(url, params = card_params).json()
    print('{}: {}'.format(ix+1, product['name']), end=' ')
    q = []
    for i in r['data']['products']:
        for j in i['sizes']:
            for k in j['stocks']:
                q.append(k['qty'])
    print(' '.join(str(x) for x in q))
```

###### Вывод:

```
1: iPhone 13 128GB (Global) 522
2: iPhone 13 128GB (Global) 36
3: iPhone 11 64GB (Global) 347
4: iPhone 13 128GB (Global) 689
5: iPhone 13 128GB (Global) 594
6: iPhone 14 128GB (США) 42
7: iPhone 11 128GB (Global) 389 1 3
8: iPhone 14 128GB (Гонконг) 17
9: iPhone 13 256GB (Global) 34
10: iPhone 13 128GB (Гонконг) 24
```

Первую часть кода про каталог / поиск и параметры очень подробно рассказал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1512425/531666).
Для каждого `product` идём в карточку и забираем количество. Три цикла — это dirty hack. Обратите внимание на 7 позицию, там три числа. На самом деле их ещё больше, по хорошему надо ещё забирать расцветки из **basket-10.wb.ru**…**card.json**, метчить id размеров с понятными названиями и разобраться что такое **wh**, скорее всего это id складов и названия у них тоже, наверняка, есть.

По расцветкам, у каждой расцветки свой **nm_id**.
Но это оставим на домашнее задание. Принцип, я думаю, теперь понятен, а на описание циклов, возможно, уйдёт не один день.

Comment: Как можно проверить количество товаров без насилия над корзиной?

Comment: @ElenaChuvasheva дополнил

Answer (score 0):

кол-во товаров можно получить по запросу https://card.wb.ru/cards/v1/detail?appType=1&curr=rub&dest=-1257786&spp=30&nm=15686973, где nm - это номер страницы товара.
в ответ приходит json, в нем ищем sizes, а в нем stocks (массив) - тут все остатки по всем складам поставщика.
Заголовки в запросе простейшие, куки не нужны.
можно просто в браузер вставить строку запросу и получить json.

```json
   "stocks": [
        {
            "wh": 117986,
            "dtype": 4,
            "qty": 1,
            "priority": 46078,
            "time1": 5,
            "time2": 69
        },
        {
            "wh": 212032,
            "dtype": 1,
            "qty": 94,
            "priority": 54801,
            "time1": 25,
            "time2": 39
        }
    ],
```