# Как я могу вытащить html код из get запроса?

Tags: python, парсер, request, web-scraping

Пытаюсь спарсить данные о товарах (Название, цена, бренд). Когда посылаю get запрос, в ответ мне приходит html страница, где часть товаров есть, а часть нет. Она будто урезанная. В браузере если смотреть html, который возвращает сайт в запросе, там все есть. Но как только дело доходит до запроса в requests, то информация не полная. Как я могу получить такой же html документ в ответ, как и в браузере? Заголовки задаю такие же, какие были в запросе.

Код

```
import requests

url = "https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--blendery/54931/listwas_redir=1&rt=12&rs=eJwzEg5gnMXId2Hjhd0Xtl7Ye2HLha0XGwBm_Au4&suggest=1&suggest_type=category&suggest_text=^%^D0^%^91^%^D0^%^BB^%^D0^%^B5^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^B4^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^80^%^D1^%^8B&hid=765280&allowCollapsing=1&local-offers-first=0"

headers = {
'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
'Referer': 'https://market.yandex.ru/',
'Origin': 'https://market.yandex.ru',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'}

 response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
 result = response.text

 with open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
 file.write(result)
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: По url 400, что спарсить хотите не понятно, можно было бы просто поисковой запрос написать. А так подходы мало чем отличаются от того, что происходит на [wildberries](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513272/Парсинг-количества-товара-на-wildberries/1513985#1513985).

Comment: При парсинге Wildberries, у них есть запрос, который возвращает товары в json формате и с ними работать легко. На скринах yandex market. И пытаюсь спарсить соответственно страницу оттуда. Искал по запросам и не нашел ответ в json формате, только целые страницы. И только в этом ответе есть нужная для меня информация. Соответственно мне придется разбирать всю страницу, но для этого нужно сначала ее получить в таком же виде, как и в браузере

Comment: Вы мне что-то доказать хотите? Тут тоже выдаёт json, см. POST запрос к API по адресу `?r=src/resolvers/search/resolveRemoteSearch:resolveRemoteSearch`, данные там все есть, но чтобы собрать их в удобочитаемый вид, надо заморачиваться также как с wildberries. Если что-то не получается, учитесь формулировать свой вопрос, либо обращайтесь на фриланс биржи. То что вы забираете в url — это doc страница, в которой содержится минимум товаров, на случай, если на клиенте будет заблокирован JS, т.е. нединамическая страница с минимальным набором.

Comment: Доказывать я вам ничего не хочу. Вам не понятно, что я хотел спарсить, я вам и объяснил. Вайлдберис я парсил уже. Если вы не понимаете вопроса, это не значит, что я его не могу сформулировать. Так же если вам что то не нравится в формулировках, можете просто выйти и не отвечать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже написал в комментарии, api у Яндекса есть, и [json](/questions/tagged/json) он возвращает без проблем.
Повторюсь, что [изучать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1513985/531666) возможности и ограничения api сайтов дело занимательное, но трудозатратное, ещё более трудозатратно разжёвывать это всё, поэтому здесь вкратце.

#### 1. Headers

Api ничего не отдаст, если не будет необходимых headers. И‥ нет, referer, origin, User-Agent и т.д. не являются необходимыми. Необходимы только те что прилетают с антикапчи. Хотя эмулировать всё подряд, чтобы претвориться браузером не так уж и плохо.

Собственно, быстрее всего забрать из браузера, можно руками, можно через [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium):

```python
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://market.yandex.ru'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
sk = driver.execute_script("return window.state['user']['sk']")
skid = driver.get_cookie("skid")['value']
driver.quit()
```

В Selenium сильно застревать не будем, забрали то что нужно и вышли.
Капча может попросить поставить галочку, это также можно сделать автоматически:
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element('id', 'js-button'))`

Всякие обвески в виде `WebDriverWait`, обёрток по поводу того открылась страница или капча — оставлю на домашнее задание, тем более вопрос не об этом. Капчу также можно решить не прибегая к Selenium, но по подобным наработкам есть смысл делать SaaS монетизацию, вряд ли кто-то в ответах будет решение капчи расписывать. Главное — получили автоматически то что нам нужно и едем дальше.

По итогу в headers нужны:

- content-type
- cookie (причём исключительно сессионные работать не будут, надо именно передать)
- sk

#### 2. Cookies

В браузере их много. Можно перенести все, и тогда requests заработает как надо, иначе будет выводить на антикапчу. Конечно же, все cookies не нужны, достаточно получить:

- _yasc
- i
- yandexuid
- spravka
- skid

Как их получать, опять же, подробно останавливаться не буду, есть другой ответ упомянутый в начале о том как это делать. Но если использовать cloudscraper, то достаточно будет указать лишь skid.

#### 3. API

```python
import cloudscraperfrom 
from urllib.parse import urljoin as UJ
s = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

api = r'/api/resolve/'
params = {'r': 'src/resolvers/search/resolveRemoteSearch:resolveRemoteSearch'}
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cookie': 'skid={}'.format(skid),
    'sk': sk
}
body = {
    "params": [
        {
            "suggest_text": "Блендеры",
            "page": 1,
            "withResults": True
        }
    ]
    , "path": ""
}
r = s.post(UJ(url, api), params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
```

Получаем response 200, внутри либо товары, либо предупреждение о капче, если предупреждение, см. пункт 1, нужны новые sk и skid.

`body` значительно сокращён. Лично я не вижу особой разницы в наличии или отсутствии томошних параметров, по сути самые важные `suggest_text` и `page`. По мне результат удовлетворительный. Без `path` работать не будет, но можно указать пустой, или при особом желании сократить до `/catalog--blendery/54931/list`. Если же необходимо 1 в 1 получить то что выдаётся в браузере по дополнительным фильтрам, есть смысл просто скопировать тело запроса из браузера.

Информации там просто тьма, на любой каприз, даже та, которая на страницу не выводится, про склады и т.д. Но т.к. задающий вопрос в комментариях тоже капризный, и в вопросе упёрто отказывается писать что хочет получить, ограничимся названиями, ценой и ценой без скидки. Также стоит отметить, что порядок товаров может не совпадать с тем что на сайте, т.к. сортировка идёт стандартно по ключам в dict.

```python
for offer in r.json()['results'][0]['data']['collections']['offer'].values():
    print(offer['modelAwareTitles']['raw'])
    print(offer['discount']['currentPrice']['value'], end='\t')
    print('\u0336'+'\u0336'.join(str((offer['discount'].get('oldPrice') or {'value':''})['value'])))
```

###### Вывод:

```
Погружной блендер VITEK VT-3407
1299    ̶1̶7̶9̶0
Стационарный блендер Polaris PTB 1834G
6990    ̶
Погружной блендер Zigmund & Shtain BH-342 M
5590    ̶6̶9̶8̶8
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F90
1999    ̶2̶3̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F96
2599    ̶5̶4̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1589AL
7699    ̶9̶1̶1̶2
Блендер REDMOND RSB-M3427
4640    ̶
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F56
1699    ̶2̶4̶6̶2
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2994
4124    ̶
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F94
1699    ̶3̶1̶5̶9
Блендер Zigmund & Shtain BH-345 M
3190    ̶6̶9̶9̶0
Погружной блендер с миксером HiSTORY IHB-527, стальной/черный, soft-touch
4590    ̶
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2995
1749    ̶3̶9̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1594
2999    ̶3̶7̶3̶7
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 7045X
6620    ̶7̶7̶8̶8
Стационарный блендер Kitfort KT-1359
7990    ̶9̶5̶9̶0
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 9125XS
7990    ̶
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1476
2899    ̶6̶1̶9̶9
Блендер HYUNDAI HYB-H3845
1760    ̶2̶5̶9̶0
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42M33
1799    ̶2̶5̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1385
2800    ̶
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 3137 Sauce +
5594    ̶
Блендер погружной Scarlett SC-HB42F97
1399    ̶1̶9̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F91
1250    ̶2̶9̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F61
2133    ̶2̶9̶8̶9
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 3020 Pesto
3690    ̶
Стационарный блендер NutriBullet Pro exclusive
5990    ̶8̶9̶9̶0
Погружной блендер Braun MQ5207
3990    ̶
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42M47
2782    ̶3̶5̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Kitfort КТ-3052
2990    ̶
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1380 Silent
3499    ̶4̶2̶1̶0
Погружной блендер Bosch ErgoMixx MS 6CM6120
5426    ̶
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42M49
2624    ̶
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2951
2999    ̶3̶9̶9̶9
Стационарный блендер Kitfort KT-1340
2990    ̶
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2944
2800    ̶
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 3035 Sauce
4325    ̶
Стационарный блендер Kitfort KT-3034
2380    ̶
Погружной блендер Scarlett SC-HB42F39
1498    ̶1̶9̶1̶9
Погружной блендер Braun MQ 535 Sauce
3670    ̶
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2993
3390    ̶4̶4̶9̶9
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1065
2699    ̶3̶3̶0̶6
Погружной блендер Bosch MSM 14100
1440    ̶2̶3̶2̶6
Погружной блендер Bosch MSM 2610B
2901    ̶
Блендер погружной bosch
4100    ̶9̶8̶5̶6
Погружной блендер LUMME LU-1886
1107    ̶3̶7̶4̶0
Блендер домашний/стационарный/измельчитель льда/для смузи/кофемолка/5000 Вт, стеклянный кувшин 2.5 литра, регулировка скорости работы, красный
4999    ̶9̶9̶9̶9
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2913
3240    ̶
Блендер погружной Moulinex Quickchef DD653832 черный, 800 Вт
5499    ̶6̶9̶9̶0
Погружной блендер Moulinex InfinyForce Pro DD95HD10, 1200 Вт, регулировка скорости силой нажатия, 6 предметов
9499    ̶1̶2̶4̶9̶0
Блендер погружной Moulinex Optichef DD64K832, 800 Вт, 4 предмета
3810    ̶5̶3̶3̶4
Блендер погружной Moulinex InfinyForce DD944810, 1000 Вт
6999    ̶9̶7̶9̶9
Стационарный блендер Dauken MX950 PRO
15589   ̶2̶5̶4̶8̶8
ICook™ Блендер от Amway
10700   ̶1̶2̶2̶2̶3
Блендер мини Smeg, белый, PBF01WHEU
14590   ̶
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1594
2999    ̶3̶7̶3̶7
Погружной блендер REDMOND RHB-2972
3240    ̶
Погружной блендер Polaris PHB 1385
2800    ̶
Блендер портативный Rommelsbacher SVD 1400 1400Вт серебристый
18737   ̶
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2983
3390    ̶4̶4̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2995
3289    ̶3̶9̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RSB-3402
4952    ̶5̶9̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2989
7999    ̶9̶9̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2941
3270    ̶3̶9̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2943
2999    ̶3̶9̶9̶9
Блендер REDMOND RHB-2972
3490    ̶5̶4̶9̶0
Увлажнитель воздуха VITEK VT-1761
3569    ̶
Мясорубка Metropolis VITEK VT-3644
2790    ̶3̶4̶9̶0
```

Comment: Благодарю за такой подробный ответ. Очень помогли