# Добрый день! Начала недавно знакомиться с парсерами и столкнулась с такой проблемой. Див класс на сайте есть, а у меня в данных не отображается

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

JSON = 'cards.json'
HOST = 'https://catalog.onliner.by/'
URL = 'https://catalog.onliner.by/conditioners?mfr%5B0%5D=gree&mfr%5B1%5D=dahatsu&mfr%5B2%5D=alpicair&mfr%5B3%5D=denko&mfr%5B4%5D=green&mfr%5B5%5D=lg'
HEADERS = {
 'accept': '*/*',
 'user-agent': '*'
          }
def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
      return r
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='schema-product__more-wrapper')#schema-product__children-group
    cards = []
    print(items)
html = get_html(URL)
get_content(html.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужен блок schema-children, просматривая текстом html документ увидела , что там его нет.Из-за чего это могло произойти?

P.S Вот такой вывод кода, как видите контейнера чилдрен тут нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Чтобы поправить ваш вопрос вы можете нажать [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: Блока `schema-children` на странице действительно нет. Откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: Сайт генерируется динамически, поэтом, посмотрите вкладку Network в браузере, там Вы найдёте API для запроса, который отправляет JSON ответ (https://catalog.onliner.by/sdapi/catalog.api/search/conditioners?mfr[0]=gree&mfr[1]=dahatsu&mfr[2]=alpicair&mfr[3]=denko&mfr[4]=green&mfr[5]=lg&group=1), или используйте Selenium + BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Видимо имелся ввиду `schema-product_children`?

Comment: Да ,блок schema-product-children

Comment: Тогда смотрите совет @user510170 по сути там уже готовый JSON со всеми данными и парсить ничего не надо, лишь отфильтровать необходимое вам.

Comment: не совсем поняла, где именно брать json(ссылку видела, просто хочу до конца разобраться)

Comment: @karina довольно подробно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472710/Всем-привет-Запарсил-сайт-но-что-то-не-так-Вместо-вывода-опр-текста-выходят-п/1473982#1473982) расписал как пользоваться developer tools на примере сокетов, просто вместо сокетов делайте фильтр по **XHR**. Сокеты на вашем сайте, кстати, тоже есть, но выполняют несколько иные функции.