# Спарсить масло с сайта по подбору зап. частей

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Нужно чтобы при вводе марки и модели авто выдавалось масло которое подходит под конкретный автомобиль.

Сайт с которого нужно спарсить поиск: https://www.kroon-oil.com/ru/

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
query = input('Введите марку и модель авто: ')
api_url = 'https://www.kroon-oil.com/api/carlist.json'
car_models = requests.post(api_url, json={"query":query}).json()

try:
    car = car_models['response'][0]
except:
    car = car_models['response'][1]
base_url = 'https://www.kroon-oil.com/ru/product-recommendation/cars/{}/{}/{}/{}'
url = base_url.format(car['make_url_name'],
                      car['model_url_name'],
                      car['type_url_name'],
                      car['type_id'])
soup = BS(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
sections = soup.find_all('h2')
for section in sections:
    print(section.text.strip('\n'))
    section_url = url+'/'+section.parent['data-componentid']
    soup = BS(requests.get(section_url).content, 'lxml')
    try:
        products = soup.find('ul', class_='recommended-products').find_all('h3')
    except:
        break
    for product in products:
        print('\t{}'.format(product.text))
```

Comment: Вы разберитесь о чём ваш вопрос, о боте или парсинге. Если про парсинг, стоит убрать код бота как лишний. На SO не приветствуется в одном вопросе задавать несколько.

Comment: @DiMithras. Убрал лишнее. Нужно спарсить поиск с сайта

Comment: @DiMithras. все убрал) что с кодом в итоге?

Answer (score 1):

Весь представленный вами код можно сократить до нескольких строчек, если использовать XHR. Как анализировать сайты в браузере в вкладке Network можно посмотреть [в других моих ответах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:531666+%5B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%5D), например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472710/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%92%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BF/1473982#1473982).

```python
import requests
query = 'Touareg'
api_url = 'https://www.kroon-oil.com/api/carlist.json'
car_models = requests.post(api_url, json={"query":query}).json()
```

Всё, теперь у нас в `car_models` список всех автомобилей найденных по запросу.
Но дальше необходимо выбрать автомобиль и получить масло, верно?
Возьмём какую-нибудь отдельно взятую модель, например мою любимую, дизельную. Посмотрим что есть в выданном [json](/questions/tagged/json).
`car_models['response'][1]`:

```
{'label_minimal': 'Volkswagen (VW) (EU) Touareg 2.5 TDI DPF (2006-2010)',
 'label': 'Volkswagen (VW) (EU) Touareg 7L Touareg 2.5 TDI DPF (2006-2010)',
 'type_id': 31013,
 'type_url_name': 'touareg-25-tdi-dpf',
 'model_url_name': 'touareg-7l',
 'model_name': 'Touareg 7L',
 'make_url_name': 'volkswagen-vw-eu',
 'make_name': 'Volkswagen (VW) (EU)',
 'category_url_name': 'cars',
 'category_name': 'Cars'}
```

Ссылка на результирующую страницу собирается из этих данных, и по ней уже, к сожалению, api нет, придётся парсить масло со страницы.
Причём сами рекомендации масла по секциям загружаются в отдельных страницах, так что запросов будет много. Если, конечно, необходимо раскрыть все секции.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

car = car_models['response'][1]
base_url = 'https://www.kroon-oil.com/ru/product-recommendation/cars/{}/{}/{}/{}'
url = base_url.format(car['make_url_name'],
                      car['model_url_name'],
                      car['type_url_name'],
                      car['type_id'])
soup = BS(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
sections = soup.find_all('h2')
for section in sections:
    print(section.text.strip('\n'))
    section_url = url+'/'+section.parent['data-componentid']
    soup = BS(requests.get(section_url).content, 'lxml')
    products = soup.find('ul', class_='recommended-products').find_all('h3')
    for product in products:
        print('\t{}'.format(product.text))
```

#### Вывод:

```
Двигатель BPD, BPE
    Helar SP LL-03 5W-30
Дифференциал задний 
    SP Gear 1011
    Syngear TDL 75W-90
Дифференциал задний самоблокирующийся (4x4)
    SP Gear 1071
Дифференциал передний 
    SP Gear 1011
    Syngear TDL 75W-90
Коробка передач в блоке с главной передачей автом 09D 6/1
    SP Matic 4026
Коробка передач в блоке с главной передачей механ 08D 6/1
    SP Gear 5015
Раздаточная коробка 0AD
    SP Gear 1081
Гидравлические тормоза/система сцепления 
    Drauliquid-LV Super DOT 4
Усилитель рулевого управления 
    SP Fluid 3013
Система охлаждения 
    Coolant SP 13
    Coolant SP 12
```

---

По вашему коду. Лучше использовать `lxml`, если он отрабатывает, он быстрее. `html.parser` стоит использовать только когда что-то парсится неправильно и / или отсуствует.

Всё что ниже, в супе, как указал выше в ответе, найдётся в лучшем случае только одна секция.

А ещё всем новичкам крайне полезно пройти [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: спасибо) но етсь момент, добавил код и ругается на одну переменную: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python home\mytelebot1\Test.py", line 32, in <module>
    url = base_url.format(car['make_url_name'],
                          ^^^
NameError: name 'car' is not defined. Did you mean: 'chr'?    все "car" подсвечивает красным как ошибка

Comment: Может что-то схрючил, когда код выкладывал, перепроверю позже

Comment: Так, поправил с мобильного, должно работать, просто я переменную переименовал в процессе и она у меня в IPython отработала.

Comment: да. подбравил все заработало, только мне надо чтобы выводило не только по туарегу. а чтобы введите авто: например: volvo s80 D5 (D5 это модификация мотора)

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич Так замените `query = 'Touareg'` на `input` или сообщение из бота, который изначально обсуждался. Если рассматривать вариант с ботом, то, если по поиску выводит одну позицию (модель) — продолжать, если моделей несколько, вывести пользователю список в inline keyboard, чтобы можно было выбрать нужную.

Comment: ,import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
query = input('Введите марку и модель авто: ')
api_url = 'https://www.kroon-oil.com/api/carlist.json'
car_models = requests.post(api_url, json={"query":"тут тоже тогда надо: querty??"}).json() , но если так прописать то выбивает ошибку: Введите марку и модель авто: volvo s80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python home\mytelebot1\Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    car = car_models['response'][1]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич не понимаю, что у вас не получается. [Вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8bU.png).

Comment: нашел ошибку , да, теперь показывает: volvo s80 d5, но например запрос Volvo s80 d2 выдет ошибку: Введите марку и модель авто: volvo s80 d2 2013
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python home\mytelebot1\Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    car = car_models['response'][1]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич смотрите, Анатолий. Ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к списку, вероятно полностью копируя вторую часть кода из ответа, и используете индекс `1`, но т.к. по данному запросу находит единственную модель, в списке всего одна позиция доступная по индексу `0`. Вопрос был про то как спарсить, ответ дан. Читайте выше по комментариям, если вы будете делать бота, то вам между первым блоком кода и вторым необходимо сделать обвязку и проверку на количество. Если только одна позиция — выводить её, если несколько — спрашивать пользователя, какая именно ему необходима.

Comment: добавил через try, exept, теперь без ошибок проверяет два вариант, но есть пару авто в который есть раздел кондиционирования и там выдает ошибку Компрессор кондиционера 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python home\mytelebot1\Test.py", line 45, in <module>
    products = soup.find('ul', class_='recommended-products').find_all('h3')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' , запрос был по авто: renault scenic 2016 , на сайте пишет: Мы не можем предоставить стандартные реко..

Comment: как я понял в этом разделе оно не может найти текст h3 и падает в ошибку, поставил тоже try и exept , все изменения внес в шапке кода. Верно же?

Comment: и что если наш пользователь не додумается написать на англ. языке , а таких будет большинство то оно упадет в ошибку и бот встанет же? как решить этот момент?

Comment: Первый `try / except` очень плохой, во втором есть смысл не `break` ставить, а `pass` или `continue`. Если пользователь не додумается написать на английском языке, то будет пустой массив. А тут надо либо: 1. уведомить пользователя, что он не прав; 2. Перевести ввод на русском на английский, для этого есть библиотеки. В любом случае, всё это выходит за рамки заданного вопроса.

Comment: а чем плох первый try / except ?  как лучше его правильно написать? второй изменил на continue но тогда во всех разделах которые пустые остаются без какого либо описания, как там написать что то типо: не найдено ?

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич тем что он не несёт никакого логического смысла. Моделей может не быть, может быть одна, а может быть 50. Вы своим `try / except` смотрите только первую, а если её не будет (пусто), то обращаетесь к второй. Это очень плохо. *как написать, что не найдено?* `except: print('\t Не найдено')`

Comment: по поводу не найдено я так уже пробовал и оно пишет вот так: Система охлаждения 
 Coolant SP 16
Компрессор кондиционера 
  Не найдено
 Coolant SP 16
Кондиционирование воздуха 
  Не найдено
 Coolant SP 16 , т.е оно берет последнее найденное из раздела Система охлаждения и дублирует в последующие разделы + добавляет не найдено, как то не очень выходит...

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич давайте так. Я попробовал [ввести очень редкий автомобиль](https://www.kroon-oil.com/ru/product-recommendation/cars/noble/m12-series/m12-gto-3r/27940/160689/#!/component:160689/) и там секций в разы меньше. 4 секции простив 10 на Touareg. Если на какую-то секцию нет товаров, то она просто не будет отображаться. `try / except` здесь не нужен в принципе. Я не понимаю, что вы хотите. Если у вас что-то не получается, я бы предложил вам оформить это в новый вопрос, т.к. в текущей ситуации комментарии вышли за рамки изначального вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Можно это реализовать вот так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
query = "тут поидее должен быть input"
query = query.replace(' ', '+')
URL = f"https://www.kroon-oil.com/ru/product-recommendation/cars/nissan-eu/100-nx/100-nx-16-b13/24048/1577/#!/component:1577/"
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
dict_fuel = []
if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "lxml")
    for i in range(len(soup.find_all('h3'))):

        val = soup.find_all('h3')[i].text
        print(re.sub('[ЁёА-я]', '', val).rstrip())
```

Comment: в вашем коде показывает только по указанной ссылке на ниссан. Нужно чтобы был ввод марки и модели и по этому запросу выбивало на любое авто

Comment: я думаю автору кода не составить труда прописать input

Comment: я добавил input , можете посмотреть в шапке (отредактировал весь код) , но не понятно какую ссылку ставить, перепробовал уже много разных, покажите пожалуйста полностью исправный варинат

Comment: я добавил изображение примера

Comment: попробовал ваш вариант но оно ищет только по тому автомобилю который указан в ссылке, в данном случае это только ауди, если я ввожу в инпут любой другой бренд то выдает тоже самое по ауди

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич как по Audi? В ответе статичная ссылка на Nissan 

Comment: @DiMithras там чуть выше есть скрин с кодом , там прописан ауди)

Comment: @АнатолийКузьмич то что на скрине, да, динамики прибавилось, но динамика исключительно на производителя. Если его сменить, то ссылка битая будет. Я вам расписал как такая ссылка формируется, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь.